# How to read specific fields from XML and load into Oracle db

Tags: c#, xml, linq

**my XML :**

```
- <resources start="0" count="188">-
- <resource classname="Quote">
   <field name="name">USD/GEL</field> 
   <field name="price">2.418900</field> 
   <field name="symbol">GEL=X</field> 
   <field name="ts">1488758461</field> 
   <field name="type">currency</field> 
   <field name="utctime">2017-03-06T00:01:01+0000</field> 
   <field name="volume">0</field> 
   </resource>-  
   </resources>
```

**C# Code:**

```
 var xmlNodes = xElement.Descendants("resource")
            .Select(e => new
            {

                ConvertFrom = e.Attribute("symbol").Value,

                ConvRate = e.Attribute("price").Value,

                ConvDate = e.Attribute("utctime").Value
            });
```

I tried the above code to fetch and load into oracle but i got a below error.

> ***System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Xml.Linq.XElement,<>f__AnonymousType0`3[System.String,System.String,System.String]]***

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have misunderstood `Attribute` method, the name of the attribute is `name`, `symbol` is the value, so your query could be this way:

```
var xmlNodes = xElement.Descendants("resource")
                       .Select(e => new
                                    {

                                      ConvertFrom = (string)e.Elements().FistOrDefault(r=>r.Attribute("name").Value=="symbol"),
                                      ConvRate = (string)e.Elements().FistOrDefault(r=>r.Attribute("name").Value=="price"),
                                      ConvDate = (DateTime)e.Elements().FistOrDefault(r=>r.Attribute("name").Value=="utctime"),
                                     });
```